# MongoDB db collection linking

Tags: shell, mongodb

Suppose I have two collection in a mongoDB

students:

```
{_id: 1, name: "sa", teachers:[1,2,3]}
{_id: 2, name: "sb", teachers:[1,3]}
```

teachers:

```
{_id:1, name: "ta"}
{_id:2, name: "tb"}
{_id:3, name: "tc"}
```

now I want to query in students collection through teachers name. Like this:

```
db.students.find({'teachers.name':"ta"}).count()
```

I have read somewhere that it is possible to link collection or embed it. Is there any way to do it?

[what have I tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) I have tried `db.students.ensureIndex({'teachers':1})` but it does not work. I also think it should not work. I am going out of clue how to do it?

DUPLICATE: Well I know that there are a lot of post which has similar title, but yet I am confused!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into how relational models are done with MongoDB?

I am unsure why you think ensureindex will do anything for you here. There is no way to "link" collections, MongoDB is a non-relational database. There is also no way that a query can be defined as querying two collections separately using sub selects at the moment.

The main problem with embedding here is that you have a many to many relationship:

- A student has many teachers
- A teacher has many students

Which could create a unperformant scenario with updating here.

The best, right now, off the top of my head is to actually do the JOIN client side like so:

```
var teachers = [];
db.teachers.find({'name':"ta"}).forEach(function(doc){ 
    teachers[teachers.legnth-1] = doc._id; 
});
db.students.find({teachers: {$in: teachers}});
```

Comment: +1. teachers = db.teachers.distinct("_id", {'name':"ta"}); db.students.find({teachers: {$in: teachers}}); reads a bit better perhaps and is more bandwidth friendly